# Reference to anonymous value in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous

I took up "[99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)", and I came across [Problem 40](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/#p40) which is the Goldbach conjecture.

I came up with this solution which, actually, outputs all pairs of prime numbers whose sum is the given number:

```
def goldbach(n : Int) = {
  val lprimes = listPrimesinRange(2 to n) // all primes less than n
  lprimes.takeWhile(x=> x < (n-x)).filter(x=> lprimes.contains(n-x)).map(x=> (x,n-x))
}
```

Works perfectly, but is is not a one-liner. And this is because in the filter operation, we need to refer to the initial list of primes. Is there a way to write something like this:

```
def goldbach(n : Int) = {
  listPrimesinRange(2 to n).takeWhile(x=> x < (n-x)).filter(x=> ???.contains(n-x)).map(x=> (x,n-x))
}
```

...where '???' will be replaced by an appropriate expression?

OK, I understand that asking for a 'name' for an anonymous value is self-contradicting. But, since I'm solving this problem just for fun, this is an opportunity to find out things about Scala internals; in this figurative one-liner approach, what was initially 'lPrimes' list will actually be internally represented. Do we have access to this internal representation? Or is it something we really should avoid?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this is possible. You *could* write your own extension method which would work like this:

```
implicit class RichAny[A](x: A) extends AnyVal {
  def use(f: A => B) = f(x) // could have a better name
}
```

and use it as

```
listPrimesinRange(2 to n).takeWhile(x=> x < (n-x)).
  use(primes => primes.filter(x => primes.contains(n-x))
```

Comment: I like that approach! A generic function that will expose the collection, not the element. Inspired after this, I managed to do it by enclosing listPrimesinRange in a List[List] like that:

List(listPrimesinRange(2 to n)).flatMap(pr => pr.filter(x=> pr.contains(n-x))).takeWhile(x=> x < (n-x)).map(x=> (x,n-x)) 

Mind that 'takewhile' is relocated. It wouldn't work in its original place.